# Why isn't fill working on my svg when using props?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I expect the svg to turn red but it isn't changing at all from the color #D8D8D8. I see the fill in the svg and if I turn this into a parameter I can use it then, but I'd rather just set the fill using React props so I can set a hover via my css:

The svg code (which I got my my Sketch export):

```
<svg width="57px" height="33px" viewBox="0 0 57 33" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>Rectangle</title>
    <g id="Design" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Mobile-Copy-6" transform="translate(-196.000000, -69.000000)" fill="#D8D8D8">
            <rect id="Rectangle" x="196" y="69" width="57" height="33"></rect>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

My react code:

```
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "../../assets/rect.svg";

export const Example = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Logo fill="#C94141" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I used create-react-app with the typescript template and the Logo is identified as the type:
`React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>`

Comment: Remove the `fill` attribute form the `<g>` element.

Comment: @ccprog ahha, that worked! This was the answer I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create you Logo as a component with passing props to it which you want to keep dynamic. Try creating a component like:

```
export default ({ fill = '#D8D8D8' }) => (
    <svg width="57px" height="33px" viewBox="0 0 57 33" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <title>Rectangle</title>
        <g id="Design" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g id="Mobile-Copy-6" transform="translate(-196.000000, -69.000000)" fill={fill}>
                <rect id="Rectangle" x="196" y="69" width="57" height="33"></rect>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
);
```

and then use this component simply by

```
import Logo from "../../components/logo.js";
export const Example = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Logo fill="#C94141" />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) I should have been clearer in my question; I wanted to set properties via css so unfortunately this solution didn't quite provide that. I found my answer in the comments from @ccprog